# Anaconda prompt is giving error [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am facing a terrible issue in anaconda these days I can't install any package neither can execute any command on the anaconda prompt. Below I have attached a screenshot of the error.

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: This looks like an installation issue with Anaconda. Please see the second part of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to learn how to remove and reinstall Anaconda again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thank you for replying. it is not an installation issue I am using it since last year I have a lot of packages installed in it but it came out of nowhere while I was working.